# Multiple or single web site for company and subsidiaries

Tags: website-design, website-features, architecture

I work for a company that is specialized in servers & networking Equipment. The company holds 3 subsidiaries that have different IT activities (software Engineering & application performance management, IT security, Oracle based business applications). Each subsidiary has its own identity (Name, logo).

We are thinking about rebuilding the company website and the main question I struggle on is to either create a single web site for the company and the subsidiaries, or to create one for each subsidiary.

In the first scenario, the visitor have to dig deep to reach the information he wants. In the second one, he may miss an information that might be of interest.

Are there any best practices or existing cases I should know about.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question depends on the implementation too much. The statement  `In the first scenario, the visitor have to dig deep to reach the information he wants. In the second one, he may miss an information that might be of interest.` is vague as it depends on how you decide to show information to your visitors and how you structure content on your website(s).

Comment: Choose one website and optimize the way how visitors can find your content (architecture of the site).

Comment: Or both perhaps. I have seen companies have a parent site with a fair bit of information on their subsidiaries and individual sites for each subsidiary with full detail. The parent site links to the subsidiary sites but the parent site does not outperform the subsidiary sites for the things that they should perform well on.

Answer (score 1):

Since each subsidiary has its own brand, it seems more logical for users to land on a site for each company with its own related domain name, rather than on a site with a different name and domain where the company info they're looking for is in there somewhere. It's probably better for SEO too - a site for TechWidgets Inc. on techwidgetsinc.com with content completely focused on TechWidgets Inc.'s services will probably appear more readily in SERPS for branded searches than if it's part of a site that encompasses various companies.

As mentioned above by [closetnoc](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/multiple-or-single-web-site-for-company-and-subsidiaries?newsletter=1&nlcode=18667%7Cade1#comment66869_63192), you can create a clear connection between all the sites. This can be done either in the main navigation, sidebars, footer, or you can even create some kind of unique navigation (maybe sticky) just to help users find out about the other subsidiaries. I would put a page for each subsidiary on each site, describing the other company and with their logo, and then a link to "find out more" on the specific site.